# C not detecting EOF

Tags: c

I'm coding a program that reads input one character at a time and determines whether it's decimal, octal or hex and converts it to decimal to be outputted. That part works, the problem is that I'm using `while((ch=getchar()) != EOF)` to go through the text, but the while loop never terminates. I've heard that EOF is equivalent to -1 and that the way to use EOF is to control+z to end the program, but I want it to be automatic. I've been using standard input as well as feeding it .txt texts, and both ways the program doesn't terminate. I was wondering if someone could take a look at my code and see where I've gone wrong.

(It's long, I'm sorry, I just don't know if it's something I've done within the cases  or not)

```
int main (void) 
{
    int ch, chVal, decVal ;

    ch=getchar() ;

    while ((ch != EOF)) 
    {
        switch ( ch ) 
        {
            case ' ' :
                /* Just read until it’s not a space */
                while( ( ch == SPACE ) || ( ch== EOL ) ) 
                        ch=getchar();


            case '0' :
                /* integer, octal or hex possibilities */
                ch=getchar() ;

                /**** HEX ****/

                if ( ( ch=='x' ) || ( ch=='X' ) ) 
                {
                    /* potential hex. So far we have read in 0x.  We need to see what's next. */                
                    ch=getchar() ;

                    if ( ch== SPACE ) 
                    {
                        /* all we had was 0x entered */
                        outputIllegalToken() ;
                        break ; /* we need to end every pass through the switch with a space char (space, eoln or eof) */
                    }

                    decVal=0 ;
                    while ( ( ( '0' <= ch ) && ( ch <= '9' ) ) || ( ( 'a' <= ch ) && ( ch <= 'f' ) ) || ( 'A' <= ch ) && ( ch <= 'F' ) ) 
                    {
                        chVal = DecToHex( ch ) ;
                        decVal*=16 ;
                        decVal+=chVal ;
                        ch=getchar() ;
                    }

                    /* ch is no longer a hex val. */
                    if ( ch == SPACE || ch == EOL || ch == EOF ) 
                    {
                        /* All is good. */
                        outputHex( decVal );
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        if ( ch=='l' || ch=='L' ) 
                        {
                            ch=getchar() ;
                            if (( ch== SPACE ) || ( ch== EOL ) || ( ch==EOF )) 
                            {
                                outputLongHex( decVal ) ;
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                outputIllegalToken() ;
                                while ( ch!= SPACE && ch!= EOL && ch!= EOF ) 
                                { 
                                        getchar();
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            outputIllegalToken() ;
                            ch = getchar() ;
                            while ( ( ch!= SPACE ) && ( ch!= EOL ) && ( ch!= EOF ) ) 
                            { 
                                ch=getchar(); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    printf("do we come here? \n");
                    count++;
                     break;
                    /* end of the 0x scenario  ch is  a space char */
                }

               /****** 0 *******/

                if ( ch==' ' ) 
                {
                    /* just a 0 */
                    outputDecimal(0);
                    count++;
                    break ; /* end of 0 alone scenario. ch is a space */
                }

                /***** 0L ******/

                if ( ch=='l' || ch=='L' ) {
                    /* if there is space after the l, it's ok. otherwise illegal. */
                    ch=getchar() ;
                    if ( ( ch== SPACE ) || ( ch== EOL ) || (ch==EOF ) ) 
                    {
                        outputLongDecimal(0);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        outputIllegalToken() ;
                        /* read to the next space */
                        ch=getchar() ;
                        while ( ( ch!= SPACE ) && ( ch!= EOL ) & ( ch!=EOF ) ) 
                                { 
                                ch=getchar(); 
                                }
                    }
                    count++;
                    break ;  /* end of 0L scenario.  ch is a space char. */
                }

                /**** Octal ****/

                if ( ( '0'<=ch )&&( ch<='7' ) ) 
                {
                    /* potentially octal  */
                    chVal=DecToHex( ch ) ;
                    decVal=chVal ;
                    ch=getchar() ;
                    while ( ( '0'<=ch )&&( ch<='7' ) ) 
                    {
                        decVal*=8 ;
                        decVal+=DecToHex( ch ) ;
                        ch=getchar() ;
                    }
                    /* no longer octal ch */
                    if ( ch== SPACE || ch== EOL || ch==EOF ) 
                    {
                        outputOctal( decVal ) ;

                    } 
                   else 
                    {
                        if ( ch=='l' || ch=='L' ) 
                        {
                            ch=getchar() ;
                            if (( ch== SPACE ) || ( ch== EOL ) || ( ch==EOF )) 
                            {
                                outputLongOctal(decVal) ;
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                outputIllegalToken() ;
                                while ( ch!= SPACE && ch!= EOL && ch!=EOF ) 
                                { 
                                        getchar();
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            outputIllegalToken() ;
                            ch = getchar() ;
                            while ( ( ch!= SPACE ) && ( ch!= EOL ) && ( ch!=EOF ) ) 
                            { 
                                ch=getchar(); 
                            }
                        }
                    count++;
                    break;/* end octal scenario  ch is a space character. */
                }

                count++;
                break ;

            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
                /* potential decimal input */

                chVal=DecToHex( ch ) ;  /* convert the character to a number */
                decVal=chVal ;          /* keep track of the overall number */

                ch=getchar() ;
                while ( ( '0'<=ch ) && ( ch<='9' ) ) 
                {
                    chVal=DecToHex( ch ) ;
                    decVal*=10 ;
                    decVal+=chVal ;
                    ch=getchar() ;
                }

                /* integers have ended.  spaces or l is acceptable. everything else is illegal */
                if ( ( ch== SPACE ) || ( ch== EOL ) || ( ch==EOF )) 
                {
                    outputDecimal( decVal ) ;
                } 
                else if ( ( ch=='l' ) || ( ch=='L' ) ) 
                {
                    /* next char needs to be space in order to be a valid long integer */
                    ch==getchar() ;
                    if ( ( ch== SPACE ) || ( ch== EOL ) || ( ch==EOF ) ) 
                    {
                        outputLongDecimal( decVal ) ;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        outputIllegalToken() ;
                        while ( ( ch!= SPACE) && ( ch!= EOL ) && ( ch!=EOF ) ) 
                        {
                            ch=getchar();
                        }
                    }
                }
                count++;
                break;
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need three `while` loops.  Just put a do-nothing in your case statement for the space, and let the outer `while` loop do its magic.

Comment: I guess you are reading somewhere EOF, and that is followed by another `getchar()` function which will eat EOF character. Either restructure your program, or add check for EOF under other `getchar` calls.

Comment: Robert you're quite right. I got rid of that while loop. 
Burgos if I use putchar() to see what the character looping in the outer while loop was and it was giving me a line break. I don't know what that means, but when I tried to change the while statement to include (ch != '\n') it didn't help either.

Comment: Try to restructure your code to have one loop with only one call to getchar. It will help you to control the reading. The inner code may be formed as a state-machine. Start with IDLE state, move to HEX, OCT or DEC states when you identify the type. The handling of 0, space and other chars differ if you are in a different context

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
            while( ( ch == SPACE ) || ( ch== EOL ) ) 
                    ch=getchar();
```

will cause an infinite loop if the last character in the input is a space. I think you meant simply `( ch == SPACE )`, but replacing the entire statement with just `break;` will work too.

There may be other bugs also ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a lexer. Instead of rebuilding this complex wheel, it will be an easier program for you to write and maintain if you use [flex/lex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/). This is a flex converter for hex, octal's starting with zero, and passthrough of everything else:

```
%{

%}
%option 8bit outfile="scanner.c"
%option nounput nomain noyywrap
%option warn

%%

0x[0-9]+ { fprinf(yyout, "%d", yytext); /* hex conversion */ }
0[0-9]+  { fprintf(yyout, "%d", yytext); /* octal conversion */ }
.|\n { ECHO; /* print everything else out unmodified */ }

%%
int main(int argc, char **argv);

int main (argc,argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{
yylex();
return 0;
}
```

Just compile with:

```
flex -Cf scanner.l 
gcc -O -o wordConverter scanner.c
```

It accepts input on stdin and outputs until EOF.

Comment: Writing code to reinvent the wheel is good for the soul, and it aids in learning.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Then why isn't she starting with writing her compiler? :) The details of state machines are notoriously difficult to debug, and flex does a better job. So, unless the reason for building this program is to specifically write a state machine, there is really no reason to do so.